# Java how to stop freezing linux operating system, while running like this?

Tags: java, linux, swing

I have a one problem where my application freeze. When i use `new P2P("string");` which is a heavy weight GUI.

My confusion is what is the best way to run it inside this while loop? So that it does not freez the whole OS?

Example use case:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
      byte[] buf = new byte[5024];
      int bytes_read = 0;      
      bytes_read = sockInput.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
      String data = null;
      data = new String(buf, 0, bytes_read);
      System.out.println("[TCP]: incomeing data: " + bytes_read + " bytes, data=" + data);

      //
      // get some commands on TCP parse it and trigger this
      //
      new P2P(main.my_info_array);
      // After some time the whole OS freeze requires shutdown reboot physically
      // how to improve it

    }
  }
```

Comment: What's P2P? Without knowing what it does and how it behaves, it's unlikely anybody can help

Comment: Q: Can you <Ctl-Alt-F1> to another console, or "ping" or "ssh" in to the host when the "freeze" occurs?  Can you do a "ps -eaf" to see whether it's CPU bound or memory bound?

Comment: @YumYumYum - could you please let us know if any of "<Ctl-Alt-F1>", "ping" and/or "telnet/ssh" work?  Could you please try to get a "top" and/or "ps -eaf" output, if possible?

Comment: @paulsm4: no none works at that time.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: P2P is a swing GUI interface with lot of icons and background images, the GUI is just a JWindow, Jbutton combination

Comment: When/how does the P2P constructor return?  Are you launching many instances of P2P?  Can you at least add the code for the P2P constructor?

Answer (score 2):

Execute the long-running task in a background thread (i.e. a thread other than the Event Dispatch Thread). This is required because Swing is single-threaded. For more information, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: We need more info about this "freeze" from the OP.  If the application is hung (but the OS is fine) a thread is a good idea.  Otherwise, if "P2P()" is actually trashing the system, we need to know *how* and *why*, before we can fix it :)  Knowing if we can "ping", or trying to run "top" or "ps -eaf" is definitely a good start.  IMHO...

Comment: Exactly. The OP's problem isn't that he's freezing the GUI but rather that he's freezing the system. I think that this answer is a bit premature and over-simplistic.

Comment: @paulsm4, Fair enough! To Hovercraft, I agree with the premature bit, but don't see how this answer is "over-simplistic", given what I'm addressing in the answer.

Comment: @paulsm4: when he P2P() is launched after minute or random duration. It freeze. Freeze i mean whole system freeze, so like dead lock, nothing works. I need physical reboot/shutdown. no poing no terminal nothing works no mouse, keyboard nothing.

Answer (score 0):

OK, please do the following:

1) Tell us your OS (e.g. CentOS 5.5), h/w (e.g. 4-CPU 2.4GHz Pentium, 2GB RAM) and JDK (e.g. Sun Java, 32-bit 1.6.0_21).

2) If possible, specify a link to your P2P library, and the version#.

3) Modify your code so that it only reads the socket and calls P2P *once* (i.e. please comment out the loop).

4) Run "top" in a separate terminal window.

5) Run your program.  Observe if your program suddenly starts eating a lot of memory and/or a lot of CPU.  What does "top" last say before it freezes?

6) Report back what you find.